# How can I unattach an element from another element in the XAML tree?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

In my Silverlight application, I load all the **images** I need at application **start** and store them in a **dictionary**.

Then as I need them I **pick** them out of the **dictionary** and attach them in XAML trees etc.

However, I have the problem that if I attach an Image object to a **Grid**, then want to use that image **again**, it tells me:

> The image element is already a child
>   of another element.

**How can I run through my dictionary and "detach all images from parent XAML elements"?**

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a viewmodel with an observablecollection of ImageSource objects, which is bound to an ItemsControl of some type in the UI?  Or does Silverlight not have that kind of infrastructure?

Comment: It might help if you explained why you construct concrete images in a dictionary at the start? Is this for performance?  Avoiding async image loading?

Comment: @anthonywjones I do it for user experience, e.g. loading 100 images at the beginning with a nice animation etc. and then having very fast image search/display is a better experience for the user than having to wait every time new images need to be accessed.

Comment: @will that is possible, but I have experienced the more dynamics you have (images, styles, sizes of images can change), the more straightforward it is to just do it in code e.g. http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=365, but keep the MVVM approach in mind since I understand the advantages (ability to unit test, etc.) but then, you don't always have to unit test your UI, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of holding a dictionary of `Image` controls hold a dictionary of `ImageSource` instead.  A single instance of an `ImageSource` can be assigned to multiple to `Image` controls.

However I suspect that creating an ImageSource on its own will not download the actual file until there is a demand.  If that is the case your initialiser would still need to create a list of images that use these images sources and wait for all to indicate they have loaded.  Then you could keep a dictionary of `ImageSource` and discard the list of actual `Image` controls.

Comment: thanks for suggesting this, what I do now is I think what you were suggesting: put the BitmapImages themselves directly in the dictionary, then let Images assign their ImageSource to any bitmap image it wants as many times as it wants, works fine and I don't have the above problem of trying to unattach elements from the visual tree

Answer (score 1):

```
        Grid parentGrid = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(image) as Grid;

        if (parentGrid != null)
            parentGrid.Children.Remove(image);
```